# return value from nodejs function

Tags: node.js

Please, help me
I have a script

```
export    function GetKey(inn, res) {
    try {
        const body = {
            7709798583: {
                name: 'someName',
                key: '123'
            },
            7718266352: {
                name: 'otherName',
                key: '123'
            }
        };
    res(body[inn]['key']);

    } catch (err) {

       res('0000000000000');
    }
};
```

In other file I try  to use this function

```
GetKey(param, (name) => {
            console.log(name);
        });
```

It's ok. but I need to return callback to the parametr. How?

```
 var param =  GetKey(param, (name) => {
            return name;
        });
```

is not correct and return undefined

Comment: you can't return a value from inner callback. you must use another callback to use `name` or use promisejs( http://promisejs.org )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how callbacks work; although, you can fake that behavior using `Promise` and async-await syntax.

If you want to write your code like you have it, you'll want to put the rest of your logic in a function and pass it directly to your callback:

```
var param = ''

var allYourLogic = name => {
    // YOUR LOGIC
    param = name
}

GetKey(param, allYourLogic);
```

Or you can simply inline your logic:

```
GetKey(param, (name) => {
    param = name
    // YOUR LOGIC
});
```

Using the `Promise` syntax, this is how it looks:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    GetKey(param, resolve)
})
.then(name => {
    param = name
    // YOUR LOGIC
})
```

Lastly, using the async-await methodology:

```
var param = (
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        GetKey(param, resolve)
    })
)
```

Really though, it seems like you're doing something wonky which is why you're running into this issue in the first place.

Your entire application will act like it's asynchronous as soon as you use a callback because the callback doesn't execute immediately in Node.js's event loop. Instead, the current function you're in will finish executing before the `GetKey` function calls the callback method.

Comment: Sawtaytoes,  it is a really clumsy attempt. :) Фll because of inexperience. Thanks for the advice.